# FOMARTO (ORDEN) INPUT DATE

Tags: html, css

Tengo un `input date`, y me ordena los digitos en `DIA-MES-AÑO`
Necesito que el orden sea `MES-DIA-AÑO`

¿Como puedo ordernar el formato?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar una function para cambiar el formato.
Aqui estamos aplicando los cambios con un `change` y un `parseDate`

```
$(function(){ 
     $("#to").datepicker(); 
     $("#from").datepicker().bind("change",function(){ 
      var minValue = $(this).val(); 
      minValue = $.datepicker.parseDate("mm/dd/yy", minValue); 
      minValue.setDate(minValue.getDate()+1); 
      $("#to").datepicker("option", "minDate", minValue); 
     }) 
    });
```

Referencia:
http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/WArtA/